# Docker base image running slowly Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, radix, docker

So I have docker set up on OS X by using boot2docker. I have everything working, however, when I run `docker run -i -t base /bin/bash` it works, the prompt shows up... but it is EXTREMELY slow. By slow, I mean that if I would type one character, it takes about 30 seconds to a minute for that character to show up on the screen. I checked my Activity Monitor to make sure my system wasn't low on memory but that was not the case. It was showing around 85% of idle memory while this process was running. I was curious to see if anyone else on OS X was experiencing issues like this. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Docker are you running? Keep in mind they *just* started supporting OSX so it might have some quircks

Comment: Do you see a lot of disk activity while this happens? And how long does it take to get a response if you run e.g. `docker run ubuntu echo hello` ?

Comment: @RezaSanaie I am using version 0.8.1. @jpetazzo Yes, my disk activity (IO) spikes when ever I start typing at the prompt and when I run `docker run ubuntu echo hello` it takes a little less than 2 seconds

Comment: Same problem here, it's a known issue: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced the very same problem and as Julian already stated, it's a known issue. But, there is one [post in that issue-thread](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/148#issuecomment-35084716) that worked for me (well, at least an adapted version of it).

```
./boot2docker stop           # stop a currently running deamon-instance
./boot2docker delete         # remove the vm
rm -rf boot2docker.iso       # in my case I had a (very old) iso-image
```

At this stage any new attempt to re-initialize the boot2docker-vm failed for me. So I was forced to re-install boot2docker itself (and as it turned out I had a very old version). You can do this via Homebrew or with the new installer (whereas, the solution demonstrated in the [docker-docu](http://docs.docker.io/installation/mac/#installing-manually) doesn't work anymore). In any case, don't forget to set the DOCKER_HOST variable correct as explained in the documentation:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:4243
```

After re-installing boot2docker the following commands should work again:

```
./boot2docker init           # fetches a brand new vm image and initializes
./boot2docker up             # now we're back in business
```

That did it for me - now the performance is as expected

```
 docker run -i -t --rm dockerfile/ubuntu /bin/bash
```

gives me an (almost) instant bash-prompt.